# Snowflake Geography Intersection Issue

Tags: sql, database, geolocation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geo

I am trying to make a geographical intersection on Snowflake, but this query fails:

```
    SELECT
    coords."st_geom",
    geo_info."LABEL" AS "zone_name"
  FROM etl.dbt.geographical_coordinates as coords
INNER JOIN etl.dbt.stg_boundaries as geo_info
ON ST_INTERSECTS(TO_GEOGRAPHY(geo_info."BOUNDARIES"), coords."st_geom")
```

The error I get is:

`100217 (P0000): Geography validation failed: Edge (10.553418,43.281543) -- (10.529078,43.276311) crosses edge (10.534406,43.277456) -- (10.520640,43.300030)`

Therefore, I changed a bit my query like:

```
ON ST_INTERSECTS(TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY(geo_info."BOUNDARIES"), coords."st_geom")
```

This seems to work, however, it returns `LABEL` columns with `NULL` values. I guess this is due to the fact that edges might crosses.
How can I fix this?
`BOUNDARIES` is a `VARCHAR`